# Checksums comparison on linux

Tags: linux, bash

I have two large files with 200k and 100k lines. The files contain two columns each: the checksum and the path from which it was taken. The first file contains paths, half of which are in the second file and half of which are not. My goal is to compare checksums of files along their path.

I tried to use diff but it doesn't work correctly on all lines. Then I wrote a script to compare file paths first, then checksums if the paths matched. But with such a large number of lines, the script takes an incredibly long time to complete.

```
#!/bin/bash

IFS=$'\n'
del=$' '

while read LineG
do
        while read LineA
        do
                if [ ${LineG#*$del} = ${LineA#*$del}  ]
                then
                        if [ ${LineG%%$del*} != ${LineA%%$del*}  ]; then
                                printf "%s\n%s\n\n" $LineG $LineA >> "./diff.txt"
                        fi
                        break
                fi
        done < $2
done < $1
```

How can I solve this problem? How can the process be optimized to run faster?

Comment: `checksums of files along their path` What path? So what do you want to do with missing files? `${LineG#*$del}` Please read https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001

Comment: I don't see any checksum being done in your code, but why re-invent the wheel? You already have several checksum tools ready at your disposal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would:

```
# Join on filenames
join -j2 -o 1.1,2.1,1.2 <(sort -k2 file1) <(sort -k2 file2)
# Print filenames with mismatch checksum.
awk '$1 != $2{ print $3 }'
```

Comment: I tried to replace the delimiter with ':' using '-t:' option but got the error join: /dev/fd/63:4: is not sorted. By using --nocheck-order I am losing lines. With a space as a delimeter, everything is ok, but some paths in the files contain spaces. What is the correct way to make ':' a delimiter?

Comment: `join -t: .... sort -t: ... sort -t: .... awk -F: ...`